Best practice for integrating a CMake static library with dependencies in a Zephyr project
I have a well-established CMake-based static library that depends on other static libraries, which are included using the FetchContent_* mechanism. I am trying to integrate this library into a Zephyr project without modifying the library and its dependencies, or duplicating the CMake configuration to make it compatible with Zephyr’s conventions.
The issue I’m encountering is that when I use FetchContent_* from Zephyr, the library and its dependencies are not compiled with the correct compiler flags. This results in linker errors due to mismatched CPU architectures.
To work around this, I call link_libraries(zephyr_interface) just before FetchContent_MakeAvailable(...), which solves the problem.
Is there a better solution?
Is there a best practice for integrating such libraries in a Zephyr project without modifying them or duplicating their CMake logic?
